# Using Xcode / Interface Builder remotely

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, interface-builder

I do most of my dev work on a mac book pro but on occasion I connect remotely to my mac mini to do some stuff remotely - usually from a PC. I am using googles chrome remote as this gives me good flexibility.

I am struggling with CTRL-Drag in interface builder. Hooking up events is ok as I can right click etc... But I am trying to add a constraint between two UIViews. Typically I would control drag from one to the other then a constraint menu would appear.

I have been unable to find any way around this that will work remotely where control & drag do not occur. has anyone got any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately CTRL+Drag is not working on remote connection which is a bug of OS X Screen Sharing service. I personally opened a bug for that problem to Apple and it was closed as "Duplicated". So Apple knows the problem for years (this problem exists for at least 6 years AFAIK), but still haven't fixed it.

You can find an alternative workaround on following page:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/158717/xcode-6-1-storyboard-ctrldrag-doesnt-work-not-even-blue-line

Comment: Hi Thanks for your reply. I have been trying to find a work around for CTRL_Dragging from 1 UIView to another - this opens up a constraint menu in the storyboard. I can't seem to emulated this functionality by right clicking. Is there a work around for this? Right clicking seems to allow you to hook up the various UI items with events / outlets etc... only - or am I missing something?